# Webpack bundling behavior for star imports in React.js , webpack 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

lets say I have util.js file in my react project, that has various handy functions I am using across react components.

```
export const functionOne = () => {
   //does something
  return some_value;
}

export const functionTwo = () => {
   //does something
  return some_value;
}

export const functionThree = () => {
   //does something
  return some_value;
}
```

and lets consider these 2 scenarios.

First scenario where we are using * imports in react compoent `<ComponentA />`

```
import React, { useState } from react;
import * as util from "./util.js";
const ComponentA = () => {
   return <button onClick={() => util.functionOne()} > Button </button>
}
export default ComponentA;
```

Second scenario where we are not doing * import and only importing some specific functions that are inside util.js file in `<ComponentA />`

```
import React, { useState } from react;
import { functionOne } from "./util.js";
const ComponentA = () => {
   return <button onClick={() => functionOne()} > Button </button>
}
export default ComponentA;
```

Now when webpack bundles this component `<ComponentA />` in first scenario where I am using star import, does it include all the functions inside utils in bundeled file ?

I am not using Create React App.

Comment: Why don't you try it and check? :) This question deals with tree-shaking = how well Webpack is able to exclude unused code. Ideally, Webpack can skip unused imports even if you import using the star. I think that the setting `optimization.usedExports` might be good to look into. Also, possibly it could play a role whether you're outputting esm modules or cjs modules, but it might be that Webpack may prune unused code no matter. If `util` is a different package, these rules would involve some additional aspects.